# How do i use xargs to create soft links from my html files?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

The problem is that I have a directory full of html files.  However, when I open the folder in Firefox it is difficult to navigate because when I open the folder there are also all of the associated html folders.

I tested using a `ln -s` of just the html to a seperate viewing directory and tested it and it worked.

Now my problem is trying to set up these `ln -s` across hundreds of files but I cannot figure out how to do this.  I thought that the best way would be to use `xargs` on `ls` output but I cannot seem to get the syntax to work.

I believe that my problem is that I need to parse two sets of arguments to `ln -s` but I cannot get it to work

I have tried many different variations of the below but can't get the syntax to work.  I've also tried using gnu parallel but still can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
ls Downloads (filenames) | grep html | xargs ln -s ~\Downloads\(filenames) ~\ViewingDirectory\(filename)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is that on windows?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.  Show us the directory structure you currently have, where you want to create the symbolic links, and what you want them to reference.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick responses.  I do appreciate it.  It seems like i dont really admittedly understand xargs (ive gone hrough the man page a couple of times but it just seems like a concept more foreign then normal).  Ill probablypursue the for loop as i understand it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the use of xargs. And you parse the output of `ls`, which is generally considered a bad idea.

A better solution would be:

```
for f in ~\Downloads\*.html ; do
    b=$(basename "$f")
    ln -s "$f"  ~\ViewingDirectory\"$b"
done
```

Comment: Im curious about if their is a particular reason why ls is discouraged?  is it just because the large variation of output and dificulty with parsing it?

Comment: `ls` is not discouraged, parsing its output is discouraged, which is a subtle difference. Anyway, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs explains it better than I can in these few lines of comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `xargs`, you could do it as follows for example:

```sh
find ~/Downloads/ -type f -name '*.html' \
    | xargs -I@ sh -c 'ln -s @ ~/ViewingDirectory/"$(basename @)"'
```

Now, with `xargs` you could run the `ln` calls in parallel by using the `-P` flag:

```sh
find ~/Downloads/ -type f -name '*.html' \
    | xargs -P"$(nproc)" -I@ sh -c 'ln -s @ ~/ViewingDirectory/"$(basename @)"'
```

where `nproc` returns the number of processing units available.

Comment: Thanks, the @ notation is what i was looking for with xargs, i just was not able to find it on my own.

Comment: @AndyKlaj You can actually use different replacement strings, people usually go for `@` or `{}` for example.